# Split rows and columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have this image (attached) and I want to segment the quantity column and the price columns, but I don`t know how ?! and what functions to use to help me do that ?!

Any help will be appreciate . Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html ?

Comment: Do you really want to create two new images or do you want to extract the data from the image?

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage of the very regular structure of the input image you can do the following:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuKT2.jpg'); %//read image
bw = sum(img,3) < 10;  %//convert to binary mask
```

Taking the sum of pixels along the rows reveals the lines of text (positive sum separated by blanks)

```
lines = bwlabel( sum( bw,2) > 1 ); %// label each line
lbw = bsxfun( @times, single(bw), lines ); %// label each line in the mask
```

Now we can ignore the top 8 lines (header) and the last two  footer lines

```
sbw = lbw > 8 & lbw < max(lines)- 2; %// select only the relevant lines
```

We can separate the text into columns, assuming a large enough gap of at least 15 pixels

```
col = bwlabel( imfilter( single(sum(sbw,1) < 1), ones(1,15)/15, 'symmetric', 'same' ) < .9 );
```

Compute the bounding box of the selected lines of the two columns

```
st = regionprops( bsxfun(@times, sbw, col ), 'BoundingBox' );
```

Visualize the resulting bounding boxes

```
figure;imshow( img, 'border','tight' );hold on; 
rectangle('Position', st(1).BoundingBox, 'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2);
rectangle('Position', st(2).BoundingBox, 'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2);
```

Resulting with

[image]

Given bounding boxes it is fairly sttraight forward to crop

```
col1 = imcrop( img, st(1).BoundingBox ); %// crop the description of the products
col2 = imcrop( img, st(2).BoundingBox ); %// crop the prices
```

Comment: @Shai thank you for your help, i appreciate it, but there are somethings i can`t understand  like :
1-lbw = bsxfun( @times, single(bw), lines ); why i need to do this step ?! 
2- why you select thresholding value by 10 although threshold value =4 can gave the same result ?!

Comment: @user3903128 (1) please run code in debug mode and visualize `bw` and `lines` and then check the result of the multiplication of `bsxfun` - this operation basically gives each text line a different label. (2) I chose threshold 10 in an arbitrary manner, it might as well be that 4 is just as good.

Comment: @shai that`s what i did ( see the whole code in debug mode ) but ican`t understand it as a logic . i will be grateful if you explain it to me

Comment: @user3903128 `lines` is a 1D (**not** 2D) vector that count the number of "text" pixels per image row. Image rows between text lines have zero "text" pixels and thus their `lines` value is zero.  To label all image rows corresponding to the same text line I used `bwlabel` command. you can `figure;plot(sum(bw,2)>1);hold on;plot(lines);` to see how each image row is associated with a different text line. To convert this 1D representation to a labeling of all text pixels I multiply it with every column of the mask `bw` using `bsxfun` and get a mask where each text row has a different label.

Comment: @shai thank you for explanation , but could you explain this line please : 
col = bwlabel( imfilter( single(sum(sbw,1) < 1), ones(1,15)/15, 'symmetric', 'same' ) < .9 );
i`m really appreciate your patience with me

Comment: we are looking for the large gap between the two text columns in the image. `sbw` is a mask with only the relevant text line set to 1. `sum(sbw,1)` is a row vector counting "text" pixels per image column, we look for a sequence of more than 15 pixels that has not "text" pixels in them. `imfilter` of this row vector with `ones(1,15)/15` will output ~1 at the large gap and smaller numbers everywhere else. `bwlabel` then labels the two parts of the row vector. `bsxfun` is used to label all mask rows according to the labeling of the row vector.